# setupcon use a variant as default

Tags: keyboard, default, env

## Context

I'm building my complete debian system configuration,
so I'm modifying the keyboard and console setups.
I prefer not to modify the base files to keep a maximum
commpatibility and modularity. So I want to use VARIANT
(see setupcon  (5)) and load them at init.
But not sure I'm doing it right.

## Desired Architecture

*I will only use keyboard file for the following example.*

- There is the base file /etc/default/keyboard
- And two possible custom files (according to setupcon (5))

  - ~/.keyboard
  - /etc/default/keyboard.variant

### ~/.keyboard

It provides a custom behaviour per $HOME (user)

### /etc/default/keyboard.variant

A global and default keyboard setup

I would like to use the three at a time.

## Problem

The daemon calling setupcon are console-setup and console-setup-mini
(according to the coments in their initd scripts). They are started
before login shell, so won't know ~/.keyboard.

setupcon needs to be called

```
setupcon variant
```

or, looking at the sources, with a variable $VARIANT

```
VARIANT=variant
```

What is the best solution to adopt, saving a maximum modularity.

Thank you,